# SSRS 2008 R2 lock when listing subscriptions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, subscription

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

When I use the SSRS "My Subscriptions" link in the Report Manager, the browser waits for several minutes and often times out.

When checking the list of locks in SQL Activity Monitor there are a large number of locks on the `Reportserver` database with type `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` querying the Subscription table.

The ReportServer service and database are on the same SQL Instance.
I also cannot at that time open the Subscription Table, its locked.

I have checked there are no duplicate users (linked to reports or subscriptions).

There is plenty of disk space allocated to the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB datbases.

The report database has in the past been moved off an old server to the current one (backup & restored).

The error in the SSRS logfile at the time is:

> library!WindowsService_6!7780!01/18/2016-12:11:37:: e ERROR: Throwing
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException:
>   , An error occurred within the report server database.

This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database:

> dbpolling!WindowsService_6!7780!01/18/2016-12:11:37:: e
>   ERROR: PollingMaintenance: Restarting maintenance thread for the
>   following exception:
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException:
>   An error occurred within the report server database

This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.` The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding..

The reports and subscriptions are working fine, its just the subscription management interface that is not loading a lot of the time.

Thanks 
Vaughn